# Disabling Windows 10's explorer.exe on startup to run custom kiosk mode

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I need to disable explorer.exe on startup on Windows 10 in order to run an script.exe that launches several apps to run a vending machine.

How can this be done?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to avoid the desktop, and will Tablet Mode help?

Comment: Windows 10 has a Kiosk Mode.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**This solution is likely to make the system unstable and is provided for informational purposes only.**

If you add the AutoHotKey script to the startup folder, you can add the following command as the first command in the script to kill `explorer.exe`.

```
Process, Close , explorer.exe
```

From the [Process, Close documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Process.htm#Close):

> ## Close
>
> Forces the first matching process to close.
>
> ```
> Process, Close , PIDOrName
> ```
>
> If a matching process is successfully terminated, [ErrorLevel](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/ErrorLevel.htm) is set to its former Process ID (PID). Otherwise (there was no matching process or there was a problem terminating it), it is set to 0. Since the process will be abruptly terminated -- possibly interrupting its work at a critical point or resulting in the loss of unsaved data in its windows (if it has any) -- this method should be used only if a process cannot be closed by using [WinClose](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinClose.htm) on one of its windows.

This by itself only works temporarily as `explorer.exe` will restart itself occasionally, so this would need to be run in a loop.

```
Loop
{
    Process, Exist, explorer.exe
    If ErrorLevel = 0
        break
    Process, Close, explorer.exe
}
```

[Source](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/119718-how-to-end-a-task/#entry682210)

Comment: *explorer.exe will restart itself occasionally*...Explorer.exe is the default shell in Windows so if it's terminated Windows will restart it *immediately*. This solution will make the computer unstable because of the constant terminating and restarting of Explorer.

Comment: Right. The point isn't so much how quickly Explorer gets restarted, but that it *will* and it will be done *over and over*. This is visible to the end user and is not suitable for establishing a kiosk-style interface.